# Telecommute or virtual for work location on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

It would be nice to specify a telecommute as job location.

Location not type of employment.  For example, lets say I only want to work telecommute.  I can't give that as a location, so I can't complete the CV.

Answer (score 4):

It's already under `What type of work are you seeking?`, no?

Comment: It was there for me.

Comment: I was actually meaning the location, not just type of work.  It is really more of a location than type of employment.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to Telecommute and don't want to fill in the Location, can't you just put your Time Zone instead? Even for TC it's still important if you're in the same zone or 8 hours away...